# GA event tracking doesn't work

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I have the following code:

```
<a  onclick="ga('send','event','contactform','submit');"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit"/></a>
```

I also tried:

```
<input onclick="ga('send','event','contactform','submit');" type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit"/>
```

When the submit button is clicked I can't see anything in (realtime) Google Analytics. I fear I've done something wrong with the implementation.

Comment: Install GA Debugger to see if anything is sent to GA, or check in the dev console network tab for your hits. Also make sure there's no filter that's removing your hits.

Comment: I installed GA Debugger, and it's working fine because when I visit the website, I can see I have +1 visitor in realtime. The console says that "ga" is not defined.

Comment: Are you using GTM? If you are then you shouldn't use inline code like that to track into GA.

Comment: I'm not using GTM, I could install it if there is no workaround.

Comment: Did you include the normal, standard GA tracking snippet at the top of all your pages? The message you see would seem to indicate that you don't have there to create the GA object.

Comment: Yes I have, the website is running on Wordpress and the snippet is just implemented in the CMS, and I can see data in GA, just not this particular event.

Comment: Try changing `ga` to `_gaTracker` as per this forum: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/note-change-of-global-function-ga-_gatracker

Comment: I changed it, now it says that gaTracker is not defined...

Comment: OK, sorry, I'm not familiar with WP. You may need to search through their support forums, but something tells me it's with the way they've implemented GA. Also, it should have been underscore + gaTracker.

Comment: If it says "ga is undefined" either somebody has renamed the ga function (which would be slightly unusual) or you might be using the old version of the tracking code (which would still send pageviews, but not support the ga syntax).  Do you use the code snippet provided via the GA interface, or is this from a plugin or theme (and if so, which one) ?

Comment: Right now I have 2 snippets manually implemented in a theme option (theme "The7"), standard GA snippet and the snippet with the 'gaq_'-functions is implemented. Still not working.

Comment: You should only have one or the other, not both unless that is your intention. If you going the theme route, then remove the standard snippet.

Comment: If you include google analytics tracking code snipet, the ga function will start working.

I am having similar issue with yours, I even see the call to google analytics, and get a response from them as a gif, still can't see it in real time Conversions

Answer (score -1):

try wrapping it in a function something like

```
function test(){


    ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign');

}
```

then doing `<a onclick="test()">.`

Though I think the issue maybe with the implementation of your GA code. Are you using a plugin to place Google Analytics code on the website?

Comment: OP already mentioned that `ga` is undefined, so the wrapper wouldn't work either.

Comment: Probably wont, but I dont have comment privileges yet. And I wanted to ask if if they are using a plugin to place the analytics code. It will give me a better idea of how the set up is. If the implementation is incorrect it might be why "ga" is not defined